# React component with arbitrary number of children in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use TypeScript to write a React component that renders as an HTML `<audio>` or `<video>` element with multiple nested `<source>` elements, along the lines of:

```html
<audio>
  <source src="myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="myAudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

or

```html
<video>
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Configuring the component seems fairly straightforward:

```
interface Source {
    src: string,
    type: string
}

interface MediaProps {
    type: string,
    sources: Source[]
}
```

And the component itself seems like it ought to be simple:

```
const Media: FunctionComponent<MediaProps> = (props) => {
    const MediaTag: string = props.type;
    return (
        <MediaTag>
            {
                props.sources.map((s, _) => {
                        return (<source src={s.src} type={s.type}/>)
                    }
                )
            }
        </MediaTag>
    )
};
```

But when I try this, I get an error:

```
TS2559: Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

I tried extracting the `map()` call into a `const` with an explicit type of `ReactNodeArray`:

```
const sources: ReactNodeArray = props.sources.map((s, _) => {
        return (<source src={s.src} type={s.type}/>)
    }
);
return (<MediaTag>{sources}</MediaTag>)
```

but that got me the same error message, just with the substitution of Type `children: ReactNodeArray` for `children: Element[]`.

Am I going about this entirely the wrong way, or is there something I can do to make TypeScript happy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your sample:

1. Capitalized variables like `MediaTag` indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a [custom React component](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type), not a primitive HTML element like `<audio>` or `<video>`.
2. Converting the name to lower case would also be erroneous. A lower case name for a JSX tag like `<mediaTag>` means, that the tag will be treated as a [primitive built-in element](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) (also called `IntrinsicElements`). Your variable value won't be evaluated. As there is nothing like a `<mediaTag>` HTML element, you get

   > Property 'mediaTag' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Here comes a React idiomatic solution where we can get easily around your issue:

```
interface MediaProps {
  type: "audio" | "video";
  sources: Source[];
}

const Media: FunctionComponent<MediaProps> = props =>
  props.type === "audio" ? (
    <audio>{mapSources(props.sources)}</audio>
  ) : (
    <video>{mapSources(props.sources)}</video>
  );

function mapSources(sources: Source[]) {
  return sources.map((s, _) => {
    return <source src={s.src} type={s.type} />;
  });
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?esModuleInterop=true&jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMQK4DsDGNgXQYQnDwFN14BfOAMyiLgCIoSBDbBgbgChRJY4ASq2w06IRszYxOXHuRJRqbEnACyJACbAWABTpgAzoi5w4MAJ5gSALkYtUWiAzgAfRgDdgGkk+6mDEKhQmCQGtgDKgcEkANoAutwUssDyispwkUEhxv7BtgYwUCkA5n5mljZwBUXopVxJXJh4BWqa2rZoWDh4hMToZDAAPOpauvoGAHxwALxwYOMzEyZz4wB0FlYz07MM9o7OAPxwABTLpoN7uBMIICxgmdEGx-MQhqsBWaEAlBSDAPSXCBLUxfOC2U6mc6ebxAm53B4hJ4vN4fR4-f7QnzAuBfbhcagYbC4dBwW73KKI46oxERCmxOKghDLZgwIIk6mhVZk45UgA0cAA+qDplMmZC4Cy2XBBhyqsFpggDO9glQNiQFUq1VQ-hMyhRcfUgA)

Comment: PS: a capitalized `MediaTag` in combination with narrowed type in props seems to work, though I would consider this as a hack   [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?esModuleInterop=true&jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiArgHYbATEDCE4FSx8AvnAGZQ1wBEUqGnA3AChBwBkigt0SOAGUIhKGmk5BcOAGdFALg0woogOZC1MAJ5gkO9XsNDGw0THGSlcALJIAJsBQAFdmDquKpwZhY6nCiE3hCccAA+XABuwJ5IscYa8opI6jpyCkoA2gC6dsJoFNbuXj46RKQw5FQ0kMT0MAA8Ht5+AeoAfHAAvHBg-SNDKmqVxNU9PgAqKAYjY-0AdGFImTwwCsRwABQhat21KMsGA6dquOMQgRvq2UrqGyAoYEdH6tgA+gBKSbBO5guB7A5wTovQrSTRoYY4d4I5jbJHvbbMAD0A0yYMYgPsYM62IWlxWNzUgLsQiAA)

Answer (score 1):

Since `type` can only be an element, you likely want to use `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` to limit to only valid elements.

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this is one approach that might be close:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

interface Source {
  src: string;
  type: string;
}

interface MediaProps {
  type: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
  sources: Source[];
}

const Media: React.FunctionComponent<MediaProps> = props => {
  const MediaTag = props.type;

  return (
    <MediaTag>
      {props.sources.map(s => {
        return <source src={s.src} type={s.type} key={s.src} />;
      })}
    </MediaTag>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Media
        type="audio"
        sources={[
          { src: "something", type: "another" },
          { src: "more", type: "example" }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Here is the Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/audio-source-dynamic-element-xvec3).

This will produce:

```html
<audio><source src="something" type="another"><source src="more" type="example"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

```
interface Source {
    src: string;
    type: string;
}

interface MediaProps {
    type: string;
    sources: Source[];
}

const Media: React.FC<MediaProps> = ({ type, sources }) =>
    React.createElement(
        type,
        {},
        sources.map(({ src, type }) => <source key={src} src={src} type={type} />)
    );

const medias = [
    { src: "myVideo.mp4", type: "video/mp4" },
    { src: "myVideo.webm", type: "video/webm" }
];

const App = () => <Media type="video" sources={medias} />;
```